# WordPress Image Editor doesn't work/show image preview

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm having an issue with the default wordpress Image Editor.

I followed the common advice to remove PHP closing tag `?>` of every .php file that's used.

Also I tried to turn off all of the plugins, it didn't work. It works on the same server on other WP pages I developed, so it's not smth with PHP libraries.

The one thing I found is this:

`Uncaught TypeError: this.iasapi.setOptions is not a function
    at Object.setRatioSelection (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,admin-comments,suggest,postbox,tags-s&load[]=uggest,tags-box,underscore,word-count,post,imgareaselect,image-edit,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-auth-check,wp-util,jquery-ui-dragga&load[]=ble,jquery-ui-slider,jquery-touch-punch,iris,wp-color-picker,thickbox,wplink&ver=4.8.2:37)
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (post.php?post=15070&action=edit:1)`

happens when I try to set custom dimensions of image while on edit page.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you enqueuing custom JS on admin pages?

Comment: No, just custom .css file.

Comment: There are few popular and updated plugins that enqueue JS on admin page, like yoast seo and ACF, but even if I shut em off, image editor still doesn't work.

Comment: You have a .htaccess file, right?

Comment: Yes, it does some anti-hack and anti-spam blocking, you want it pasted here?

Comment: No need to paste it here, but I would revert it to the basic WordPress .htaccess config and see it that has an affect. https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Comment: I tried your solution with .htaccess and didn't make the difference

Comment: Try switching to a different theme -- 2017 or something.  That should tell us if something in the theme is causing the problem.

Comment: It works on other themes, I'm pretty sure it's about the theme, but where to look at? That's the main question I asked